# Jquery selector via parents?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this simple table ( nested )

```
 <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <th>kkkk</th>
                <th>mmmm</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>a</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>a</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>
                  <table border="1px" style="margin:10px">
                        <tr>
                            <th>xxxx</th>
                          <th style="background-color:yellow">yyyy</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>a</td>
                            <td>a</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>a</td>
                            <td>a</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td >a</td>
                            <td  style="background-color:red;" class="theTd">a</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

[image]

*(there aren't any table Id's here)*

I want by clicking on the `red` area , to find the **row** which the `yellow` value in.

I dont have a problem of getting the index of the `TH`.

the problem is that I want to do it by `Parents()` method only - and the red box sees **2**  `parents TR's` which have `TH`.... The xxx,yyy row and the kkk,mmm row...

Something like :

```
  alert( $(".theTd").parents("first tr  parent which contains th's").....);
```

What is the correct Selector syntax ?

http://jsbin.com/udohum/1/edit

## edit

*I don't want the ordinary  parent().parent().... cause a  `.theTd` can contain a wrapper Div's inside it etc...* - so the parent here will be DIV. ( which hurts the logic....)

Comment: parent(tr).parent(table).children(tr).children(th) should give you at least the header row items, but getting the correct one (and not the xxxx) is gonna be tricky. You probably first need to find out which column the clicked cell is.

Comment: What do you mean "I want to do it by `parents()` method only"?

Comment: @Dennis Im always using the parents to go up. So I want to make a use of it.

Comment: It is not the right tool for the job.  If you make demands like that, you may end up dismissing the correct answer because it doesn't "look right."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parents()` selects all the parents of the selected element, you can use `parentsUntil` instead:

```
$(".theTd").parentsUntil('table').find('th[style^=background]')
```

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/udohum/5/edit)

Or `closest()` method:

```
$(".theTd").closest('table').find('tr:has("th")').foo()
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes, i think closest() is the best option. yes, as your table has no other th elements you can directly select them.

Comment: WTF ? why http://jsbin.com/udohum/7/edit doesnt paint the kkk,mmm row ?  this is working and ( the  simplesd solution) but it Ain't suppose to work

Comment: @RoyiNamir For me on mac/firefox 14 it paints the xxx, yyy row.

Comment: Also for me , but it suppose to paint also the kkk,mmm row.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
$('.theTd').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().parent().find('tr > th:nth-child(2)').html());
});
```

(See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Te3QB/1/)

**UPDATE:** Using the `.closest()` selector might even be better:

```
$('.theTd').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('table').find('tr > th:nth-child(2)').html());
});
```

> `.closest()` gets the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Comment: I saw your first answer and then I wrote my Edit. but your second answer solves it... I think....

Comment: yeah, with closest you can directly get the table your item belongs to, and then do whatever you want over it.

Comment: ..you want to use parents *without* using parents?

Comment: Your second solution is working but without using parents... ( please read my edit... and Thanks.... :-))

Comment: Here it is another variant, showing more general functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/teW9B/9/

Comment: why http://jsbin.com/udohum/7/edit doesnt paint the kkk,mmm row ? this is working (and  the simplest solution) but it Ain't suppose to work

Comment: @RoyiNamir It works because you are going up the DOM tree and getting all `tr` elements (the one holding `.theTd` and the one holding its table), then going back down and finding the `th` elements under them.  The `tr` that holds kkk,mmm is not an ancestor of `.theTd`, so it doesn't get searched.

Answer (score 0):

To get the tr, try this:

```
$(".theTd").closest("table").find("tr");
```

The th is a bit more messy. We will need the nth-child, and for that we need the index:

```
$(this).closest('table').find('tr th:nth-child('+ ($(this).index()+1) +')');
```